# Sitecore Form with Salesforce Connect - Custom validations for postcode using external API

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms, validation, salesforce-connect

The custom validation for the postcode validation using Sitecore forms for a simple contact form which connects to salesforce.

I have seen multiple articles for the custom validation and also sitecore has one in documentation that is something basic.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-validation.html

Is there any way that API can be called on custom form validation?